# Code universal arithmetical sets by a hyperarithmetical set?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, computability-theory

For each n, there is a (lightface) Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>n</sub> set S<sub>n</sub> ⊆ ω<sup>2</sup> that's universal for the Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>n</sub> subsets of ω. Since {n} × S<sub>n</sub> is Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>n</sub>, there is a union R of arithmetical sets such that (n, j, k) ∈ R iff (j, k) ∈ S<sub>n</sub>. Clearly R is not itself arithmetical, and offhand I don't see why it should be Δ<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub>.

If we define the sets S<sub>n</sub> with care, is there a Δ<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub> set Q ⊆ ω<sup>3</sup> such that (n, j, k) ∈ Q iff (j, k) ∈ S<sub>n</sub>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The answer to your question is positive.

Note that the sets $S_n$ that you define can be identified with the set $TA_n$ of Gödel numbers of all first order $\Sigma_n$ sentences true in the structure $(\omega, +, \cdot)$. Let $TA$ (true arithmetic) be the set of Gödel numbers of **all** first order sentences true in the structure $(\omega, +, \cdot)$.

> $TA$ is not only hyperarithmetic, but it is an *arithmetic singleton* (this is sometimes  rephrased as "$TA$ is *implicitly definable*").  This means there is first order formula  $\phi(X)$, formulated in the arithmetical vocabulary augmented with a new unary predciate $X$ such that:
>
> For all subsets $X$ of $\omega$, $(\omega, +, \cdot, X)$ satisfies $\phi(X)$ iff $X=TA$.

The implicit definability of $TA$ is attributed to Hilbert, Bernays, Kuznecov, and Trahtenbrot in Roger's **Theory of Effective Functions and Effective Computability** (p.344. Thm XII; see also p.381, Thm  XI, where $TA$ is referred to as $V$).

It is easy to see that every arithmetic singleton is hyperarithmetic, but the converse is false. For example, there is a hyperarithmetic set that is arithmetically generic; and of course no arithmetically generic set can be an arithmetic singleton.

For more more detail on the above paragraph, as well as an exposition of implicit definability of $TA$, see the text **Computability and Logic**, by Boolos, Jeffrey, and Burgess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ali. Lamentably, I didn't mention that I seek a more direct proof that there is a set Q meeting my description. Before posting, I had already skimmed the part of Rogers you mention; I wasn't satisfied with the observation that the codeset of true arithmetic is hyperarithmetical but not arithmetical. This is partly because that observation doesn't immediately yield a Q as I described, and partly because it requires a detour through logic and model theory which, for the sake of purity, I want to avoid. I think (?) I've found a more recursion theoretic proof, posted below.

Comment: @Cole: everything else being equal, my approach to MO answers gravitates towards **not*** re-inventing the wheel. For many of us, Logic, Model Theory, and Recursion Theory are all parts of the same subject; with all due respect to purity of methods; whose charms I will never deny.

Comment: @Ali: Your approach is sensible. When I spoke of purity, perhaps I was just trying to rationalize having spent time reinventing a wheel. In any case, it was a good exercise for a student like me.

Comment: @Ali: When you said we could "identify" the sets S-n from my original posting with the codeset for Sigma-0-n truths of arithmetic, did you have something special in mind, or were you just observing that both are Sigma-0-n complete with respect to Turing reducibility?

Comment: @Cole: my choice was informed by the fact that the truth set of $\Sigma_n$-sentences of arithmetic is Turing equivalent to $0^{(n)}$.

Comment: You've helped me a lot on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the quickest answer to the original question is that the clause "If we define the sets $S_n$ with care" makes things look worse than they are.  If you use any of the standard constructions of the universal $\Sigma^0_n$ sets $S_n$, then the $Q$ obtained by stacking them next to each other will be hyperarithmetical.  Care (of a somewhat perverse sort) would be needed to get $Q$ *not* to be hyperarithmetical.  (Perverse care might consist of coding some non-hyperarithmetical set by putting its $n$-th bit into the $(0,0)$ position of $S_n$.)

Comment: Does this mean that the set R from the original question is indeed hyperarithmetical, and not just Borel? It was obtained by stacking, after all.

Comment: @Cole: I am not sure what you mean by Borel here; all subsets of $\omega$ are Borel if Borel is interpreted in its usual way.

Comment: That was silly of me! I corrected the original posting. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Indeed, I am doubly silly. Of course the R from the original question is hyperarithmetical; we've shown that there is a hyperarithmetical Q meeting my description, and Q and R are coextensive! Please cut me some slack here, as I'm just learning. And I haven't had coffee today.

Answer (score 1):

There is a (lightface) Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>1</sub> set A ⊆ ω such that for each p > 0 the Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>1</sub> set T<sup>p</sup> ⊆ ω<sup>p</sup> given by

> T<sup>p</sup>( j,x<sub>1</sub>,…,x<sub>p</sub> ) iff ∃t[ ⟨ j,⟨ x<sub>1</sub>,…,x<sub>p</sub>,t ⟩,1 ⟩ ∈ A ]

*parametrizes* the Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>1</sub> subsets of ω<sup>p</sup>, in the sense that X ⊆ ω<sup>p</sup> is Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>1</sub> iff for some j, X is the j-section

> { (x<sub>1</sub>,…,x<sub>p</sub>) : T<sup>p</sup>( j,x<sub>1</sub>,…,x<sub>p</sub> ) }

of T<sup>p</sup>. The set A is obtained by formalizing Kleene's notion of recursive derivation. (For details, see p. 127 of Moschovakis's *Descriptive Set Theory*, Second Edition. Any odd notation I use below is from that book; for instance, the asterisk will denote concatenation.)

We use A to define, for each pair p,n > 0, a set S<sup>p</sup><sub>n</sub> ⊆ ω<sup>p+1</sup> that parametrizes the Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>n</sub> subsets of ω<sup>p</sup>. It will be useful to write φ(α) as shorthand for the conjunction of this

> ∀j ∀y [ ∃i (α(i) = ⟨1,j,y⟩) ↔ (Seq(y) ∧ ∃t (⟨j,y*⟨t⟩,1 ∈ A)) ]

with this

> ∀j ∀y ∀m>0 [ ∃i (α(i) = ⟨m+1,j,y⟩) ↔ (Seq(y) ∧ ∃t ¬∃h (α(h) = ⟨m,j,y*⟨t⟩⟩)) ].

Here α ranges over <sup>ω</sup>ω and the Roman letters range over ω. Maintaining this convention, write ψ(α,n,j,y) for

> ∃m [ n = m+1 ∧ ∃i (α(i) = ⟨m+1,j,y⟩) ].

Notice that φ(α) ∧ ψ(α,n,j,y) defines an arithmetical subset of <sup>ω</sup>ω × ω<sup>3</sup>. Hence the set H ⊆ ω<sup>3</sup> given by

> H(n,j,k) iff ∃α (φ(α) ∧ ψ(α,n,j,y))

is Σ<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub> since that pointclass is closed under projection along <sup>ω</sup>ω. Moreover, induction on n reveals that

> ∃α (φ(α) ∧ ψ(α,n,j,y))

is equivalent to

> ∀α (φ(α) → ψ(α,n,j,y))

so that H is in fact Δ<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub>. Now for p,n > 0 define

> S<sup>p</sup><sub>n</sub> = { (j,x<sub>1</sub>,…,x<sub>p</sub>) : H(n,j,⟨x<sub>1</sub>,…,x<sub>p</sub>⟩) }.

By induction on n, for each p the set S<sup>p</sup><sub>n</sub> parametrizes the Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>n</sub> subsets of ω<sup>p</sup>. For the base, use the first conjunct of φ(α) to show that S<sup>p</sup><sub>1</sub> = T<sup>p</sup> for each p. For the inductive step, use the inductive hypothesis and the second conjunct of φ(α).

Finally, let Q ⊆ ω<sup>3</sup> be the Δ<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub> set given by

> Q(n,j,k) iff H(n,j,⟨k⟩)

so that (n,j,k) ∈ Q iff (j,k) ∈ S<sup>1</sup><sub>n</sub>. If the foregoing is free of errors, this answers my original question.

The motivation for that question might have been obvious, but I'll put it down for the record.

> *The set Q witnesses that the arithmetical sets are not the "effective analog" of the Borel sets.*

A classical result of Suslin is that the (boldface) **Δ<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub>** sets coincide with the Borel sets. Since the arithmetical hierarchy resembles the Borel hierarchy, one might expect that the relationship between Δ<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub> and arithmetical resembles that between **Δ<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub>** and Borel, enough perhaps that Δ<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub> and arithmetical would coincide. It is well known that this expectation is false, and indeed the Δ<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub> set Q witnesses this. For if Q were arithmetical, it would be Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>n</sub> for some n. Taking any Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>n+1</sub> set P ⊆ ω, there is some j such that for all k

> P(k) iff (j,k) ∈ S<sup>1</sup><sub>n+1</sub> iff (n+1,j,k) ∈ Q.

Since Q is Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>n</sub> by hypothesis, so is P. But then, since P was arbitrary, every Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>n+1</sub> subset of ω is in fact Σ<sup>0</sup><sub>n</sub>, contradicting the theorem that the arithmetical hierarchy is proper.